# What are the equivelant kubectl commands to this yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

I am trying to create a Role and RoleBinding so I can use Helm. What are the equivelant `kubectl` commands to create the following resources? Using the command line makes dev-ops simpler in my scenario.

### Role

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-manager-foo
  namespace: foo
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "batch", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

### RoleBinding

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: tiller-binding-foo
  namespace: foo
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: tiller-foo
  namespace: foo
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: tiller-manager-foo
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

### Update

According to @nightfury1204 I can run the following to create the `Role`:

> kubectl  create role tiller-manager-foo --namespace foo --verb=* --resource=*.,*.apps,*.batch,*
>   .extensions -n foo --dry-run -o yaml

This outputs:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: tiller-manager-foo
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
- apiGroups:
  - batch
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

The `namespace` is missing and secondly, is this equivelant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Role:**

```
kubectl  create role tiller-manager-foo --verb=* --resource=*.batch,*.extensions,*.apps,*. -n foo
```

> `--resource=*` support added on kubectl 1.12 version

**For Rolebinding:**

```
kubectl create rolebinding tiller-binding-foo --role=tiller-manager-foo --serviceaccount=foo:tiller-foo -n foo
```

Comment: For the `Role`, the `namespace` is missing, `-n` doesn't seem to work when I run `kubectl create role tiller-manager-foo --namespace foo --verb=* --resource=*.,*.apps,*.batch,*.
extensions -n foo --dry-run -o yaml`.

Comment: `-n foo` worked for me(i just tested it). Also you have to have `foo` namespace in the cluster. if  `-n` doesn't work, then you can use `--namespace`

Comment: Also `--dry-run` does not include namespace. there is issue related to this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51068

Comment: Thanks for the link, you're a boss!

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl apply -f` can submit an arbitrary Kubernetes YAML file like what you have in the question.

I’d specifically suggest this here because you can commit these YAML files to source control, and if you’re using Helm anyways then this is far from the only Kubernetes YAML file you have.  That gives you a consistent path even to bootstrap your Helm setup.

Comment: if you have specific object definitions you want, creating them from manifests is strongly recommended

Comment: Only trouble is, I want to do variable substitution for CI/CD purposes. It's much easier if I can just use some `kubectl` commands.